# Затемнение при показе progressBar

Tags: android, java

Нужно чтобы при показе круглого прогрессбара задний фон затемнялся (как при диалоговых окнах). Как реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно показать DialogFragment, в котором в View создавать круглый прогрессбар.

```
public class DialogProgress extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.indeterminate_progress, container, null);
}
}
```

indeterminate_progress.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="@dimen/action_button_min_width"
android:minWidth="@dimen/action_button_min_width">

<ProgressBar android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    style="?StyleIndeterminateProgressCompat"/>
</FrameLayout>
```